# C++ input operator overloading >>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, istream

I have a basic class called `BankAccount` that looks like this:

```
class BankAccount {
    private:
        char* accountId;
        int* ownerId;
        double* accountBalance;
    // some other methods here...
}
```

My question is about the creation of an object using the input operator. I observed that when I use it, 2 objects are in fact created, since the destructor is called twice in the end:

```
1. The implicit constructor is called
2. The values for initializing the object are provided from the stdin
3. The copy constructor is called
4. The destructor is called twice
5. The object is printed to the stdout
```

Can you explain me how does it actually work and if it can be avoided? I supposed the parameter `bankAccount` is modified directly.

My functions are:

```
// 3. input operator
friend istream &operator>>(istream &in, BankAccount &bankAccount ) {
    cout << "Enter the account ID:" << endl;
    in.get(bankAccount.accountId, SIZE);
    cout << "Enter the owner ID:" << endl;
    in >> *bankAccount.ownerId;
    cout << "Enter the account balance:" << endl;
    in >> *bankAccount.accountBalance;
    return in;
}

// 4. output operator
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, BankAccount bankAccount ) {
    out << endl;
    out << "Account id: " << bankAccount.getAccountId();
    out << endl;
    out << "Owner id: " << bankAccount.getOwnerId();
    out << endl;
    out << "Account balance: " << bankAccount.getAccountBalance();
    out << endl << endl;
    return out;
}
```

and the invocation:

```
BankAccount bankAccount;
cout << "Enter the values to build a new object: " << endl;
cin >> bankAccount;
cout << bankAccount;
```

Comment: There are no objects at all created in the function you wrote (because everything you do uses references). The behaviour you observed must be happening elsewhere in your program. Your assumption (that the bankAccount is modifed directly) is correct.

Comment: Without seeing where you actually *invoke* this operator, this question is not possible to answer.

Comment: Can you also show the << operator? Does it take a reference to `BankAccount` or does it take the object (would explain the copy)

Comment: Ah. there you go. `BankAccount bankAccount;` is the default construction. The direct input you mentioned is correct, We would have to see the output operator implementation as well, but unless it takes a reference (const or not), that is your copy-construction point. And since two objects then exist (the initial and the copy) you will get two destructions.

Comment: There you go, as suspected, the output operator param is a value-copy, so there is your copy-ctor. `friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const BankAccount& bankAccount)` will address that.

Comment: meanwhile, your output operator doesnt appear to need to be a friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As suspected you get the copy by passing the object to `operator <<` *call-by-value*

```
BankAccount bankAccount; // Default constructor call
cout << "Enter the values to build a new object: " << endl;
cin >> bankAccount; // Read in values
cout << bankAccount; // Create a copy of bankAccount and pass it to operator <<
```

To avoid this change operator << to

```
friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &out, const BankAccount &bankAccount ) {
```

This is *call-by-reference* and will avoid the copying of the BankAccount object